# What is solution to this vector problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

**Problem 38**

Suppose $|\vec{u}|=3$, $|\vec{v}|=5$ and $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=-2$. Calculate $(\vec{u}-\vec{v})\cdot(2\vec{u}+3\vec{v})$.

I am only familiar with this formula
$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = |\vec{a}||\vec{b}| \cos(\theta)$. But it doesn't help much.

Comment: Is $\circ$ the dot product?

Comment: Please complete the OP with https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and explain your work on it in order we can help you

Comment: 1) Make the effort to post your question as a question. 2) Make some effort to solve the problem (and show us what you have tried) before posting here.  This will help with formatting.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Is $\circ$ being used as the dot product?  Does the dot product follow the distributive law?  How does it behave with scalar multiplication?

Comment: let use distributive law and the hint given below, let try and show your work

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the $\circ$ denotes the dot product:
$$(\vec u-\vec v)\circ(2\vec u+3\vec v)$$
Let's call $\vec w:=\vec u-\vec v$, then:
$$\vec w\circ(2\vec u+3\vec v)$$
Because the dot product is linear:
$$\vec w\circ(2\vec u+3\vec v)=\vec w\circ(2\vec u)+\vec w\circ(3\vec v)=2(\vec w\circ\vec u)+3(\vec w\circ\vec v)$$
Now substitute back $w$:
$$2(\vec w\circ\vec u)+3(\vec w\circ\vec v)=2([\vec u-\vec v]\circ\vec u)+3([\vec u-\vec v]\circ\vec v)$$
We can use the linearity again:
$$2([\vec u-\vec v]\circ\vec u)+3([\vec u-\vec v]\circ\vec v)=2(\vec u\circ\vec u-\vec v\circ\vec u)+3(\vec u\circ\vec v-\vec v\circ\vec v)$$
Now we can use that $\vec a\circ\vec b=\vec b\circ\vec a$, and $\vec a\circ\vec a=|\vec a||\vec a|\cos(0)=|\vec a|^2$:
$$2(\vec u\circ\vec u-\vec v\circ\vec u)+3(\vec u\circ\vec v-\vec v\circ\vec v)=2(|\vec u|^2-\vec v\circ\vec u)+3(\vec u\circ\vec v-|\vec v|^2)=2|\vec u|^2-2\vec v\circ\vec u+3\vec u\circ\vec v-3|\vec v|^2=2|\vec u|^2+\vec u\circ\vec v-3|\vec v^2|=2*3^2-2-3*5^2=-59$$

Comment: (-1) for not leaving anything for the asker to do; please do not encourage people to treat this as a do-my-homework site.

Comment: @user296602 Ahh, it's you again...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize your username. Have a nice day.

Comment: @user296602 You were having a problem some days ago with my answer because I was not writing any comment on my solution. Now I've done it for this one.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use the following basic properties of [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

- $\vec a \cdot (\vec b+\vec c)=\vec a \cdot \vec b + \vec a \cdot \vec c$
- $\vec a \cdot \vec a =|\vec a|^2$
- $\vec a \cdot \vec b = \vec b \cdot \vec a $

Answer (score 0):

The dot product is distributive and commutative so we can write $(\overrightarrow{u}-\overrightarrow{v}).(2\overrightarrow{u}+3\overrightarrow{v})=2(\overrightarrow{u}.\overrightarrow{u})+(\overrightarrow{u}.\overrightarrow{v})-3(\overrightarrow{v}.\overrightarrow{v})$

Now we use the property that for any vector $A$ we have $A.A=|A|^{2}$ and we can now substitute in the given values hence $2(\overrightarrow{u}.\overrightarrow{u})+(\overrightarrow{u}.\overrightarrow{v})-3(\overrightarrow{v}.\overrightarrow{v})=2|\overrightarrow{u}|^{2}+\overrightarrow{u}.\overrightarrow{v}-3|\overrightarrow{v}|^{2}=2\times3^{2}-2-3\times5^{2}=-59$.

Comment: (-1) for not leaving anything for the asker to do; please do not encourage people to treat this as a do-my-homework site.